# What libraries / tools /components are required to build a REST api backed Line Chart app

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a task of creating a native iOS app using C# / Xamarin. The app retrives some JSON data from a REST API, and displays the results using a Line Chart. Question: what libraries / tools / components will I need to accomplish this. P.S. If anyone has a relevant code example, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data from a REST API you have lot's of ways, using the HTTPClient from microsoft, or something like [RestSharp](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp/) ...

For drawing the graphics you can look at [Oxyplot](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot).

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered, that Syncfusion actually has a library for Xamarin, which includes charts.
That should help me, as I'm using some of their other products already.